Chrome extension troubleshooting - How to print a value from the website in the console?
I'm new to chrome extensions. I am trying to develop a Chrome extension that can automatically fill forms and scrape data from specific websites.
Basically, in the website, I have an object with id "nome:nome:inputId". When I go to chrome console and run:
var a = document.getElementById("nome:nome:inputId").value

It returns to me the value I want. But I'm not able to do that in the chrome extension. It prints nothing. Why could this be happening?
The full code is below:
// manifest.json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Simple Element Value Printer",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Print the value of a specific element on the page",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "scripting"
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
  }
}

// popup.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Simple Element Value Printer</title>
  <style>
    body {
      width: 300px;
      padding: 10px;
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    #value {
      margin-top: 10px;
      padding: 10px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-radius: 5px;
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h3>Element Value</h3>
  <div id="value">Click the button to get the value</div>
  <button id="print-value">Get Element Value</button>
</body>
</html>

// popup.js
console.log("popup");
document.getElementById('fillPdfButton').addEventListener('click', () => {
  chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: { tabId: tabs[0].id },
      files: ['content.js']
    });
  });
});

// content.js
const element = document.getElementById("nome:nome:inputId");
if (element) {
  console.log("Valor do elemento:", element.value);
} else {
  console.log("Elemento não encontrado.");
}

//background.js
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: tab.id },
    files: ['content.js']
  });
});



Remove background.js, 2) Add <script src=popup.js></script> to the end of popup.html. 3) Replace fillPdfButton with print-value, 4) Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.


Hello @woxxom, I changed everything you said, but I am still not being able to acess the value in the chrome extension. I've uploaded a copy of the webpage in google drive, I would appreciate a lot if you could help me. I can pay you. I just want to acess this value in the extension, I am being able to do that on the console, but not in the extension -> drive.google.com/drive/folders/1q3c21OmbBLZcu08xiK3FXz6yIKb7K8ju?usp=sharing
